# popup that will appear once with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

According to the information from the system, I want the user to see a popup when he first logs into the application.I want.Any ideas on how to do it?

For example, a person who completes a hospital appointment evaluates the service he received with a pop-up that will appear the next time he logs into the application.I want this popup to appear only once. The person went to the hospital, completed his appointment, this information came from the system, and the next time he entered, a popup appeared directly in front of him. This is the scenario

Comment: For first time value experience you have to use shared preference or local storage like hive db/ sqlite

Comment: When pop-up appears the first time you store value in shared preference then the user came to the second time then checks value is available or not. if yes then do not show a pop-up

Comment: Like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62536438/how-to-show-a-popup-on-app-start-in-flutter

Comment: try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62536438/how-to-show-a-popup-on-app-start-in-flutter

Comment: I understand what you mean, thank you. I'll try.

Comment: If my solution is working then please up my comment so others can help too or accept my answer

Comment: This is my first time using this site. I don't know how to upvote your comment but I approved your solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use: https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

When app is start then dialog is open you to save one boolean like `isFirstTime == false`

```
await prefs.setBool('newUser', isFirstTime);
```

When your is came again into the app, have to check in pref boolean is available or not

```
final bool? isFirstTime = prefs.getBool('newUser');

if(isFirstTime){
     openDialog();
}
```

if the value is `false`  then will not show pop up